# Calculation the Taylor series of sinh

Tags: c, algorithm, int, double, taylor-series

The function calculates the value of `sinh(x)` using the following
development in a Taylor series:

[image: sinh]

I want to calculate the value of sinh(3) = 10.01787, but the function outputs 9. I also get this warning:

> 1>main.c(24): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data

This is my code:

```
int fattoriale(int n)
{
    int risultato = 1;
    if (n == 0) 
    {
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < n + 1; i++) 
    {
        risultato = risultato * i;
    }
    return risultato;
}

int esponenziale(int base, int esponente) 
{
    int risultato = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < esponente; i++) 
    {
        risultato = risultato * base;
    }
    return risultato;
}

double seno_iperbolico(double x) 
{
    double risultato = 0, check = -1;
    for (int n = 0; check != risultato; n++)
    {
        check = risultato;
        risultato = risultato + (((esponenziale(x, ((2 * n) + 1))) / (fattoriale((2 * n) + 1))));
    }
    return risultato;
}

int main(void) 
{
    double numero = 1;
    double risultato = seno_iperbolico(numero);
}
```

Please help me fix this program.

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: Sit back and think about the warning!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is actually pretty great that the compiler is warning you about this kind of data loss.
You see, when you call this:

```
esponenziale(x, ((2 * n) + 1))
```

You essentially lose your accuracy since you are converting your `double`, which is `x`, to an `int`. This is since the signature of `esponenziale` is `int esponenziale(int base, int esponente)`.

Change it to `double esponenziale(double base, int esponente)`, `risultato` should be a `double` as well, since you are returning it from the function and performing mathematical operations with/on it.

Remember that dividing a `double` with an `int` gives you a `double` back.

Edit: According to ringø's comment, and seeing how it actually solved your issue, you should also set `double fattoriale(int n)` and inside that `double risultato = 1;`.

Comment: @ringø I don't think fattoriale has to change. It all works with int's over there

Comment: Well, if you don't change the func sig and *risultato* to *double*  the `sinh(x)` will be a kind of `floor(sinh(x))`...

Comment: i don't get why if i put sinh(3) i get an inf... the result it will be 10.01787

Comment: @AmarildoAliaj Do the changes I talked about: `double fattoriale(int n)` and inside `double risultato = 1;`

Answer (score 3):

1. You are losing precision since many of the terms will be fractional quantities. Using an `int` will clobber the decimal portion. Replace your `int` types with `double` types as appropriate.
2. Your factorial function will overflow for surprisingly small values of `n`. For 16 bit `int`, the largest value of `n` is 7, for 32 bit it's 12 and for 64 bit it's 19. The behaviour on overflowing a `signed` integral type is *undefined*. You could use `unsigned long long` or a `uint128_t` if your compiler supports it. That will buy you a bit more time. But given you're converting to a `double` anyway, you may as well use a `double` from the get-go. Note that an IEEE764 floating point double will hit infinity at 171!
3. Be assured that the radius of convergence of the Maclaurin expansion of `sinh` is infinite for *any* value of `x`. So any value of `x` will work, although convergence might be slow. See http://math.cmu.edu/~bkell/21122-2011f/sinh-maclaurin.pdf.

Comment: Actually I'm not so sure about the radius of convergence. Please downvote if I'm wrong. I'm checking...

Comment: Yup, I was wrong. Radius is infinite. Rather brittle link added to the answer.

Comment: but i get an inf if i choose x >1

Comment: @AmarildoAliaj `sinh(x)` converges for any `x>1`, but `sinh(x) → ∞` when `x → ∞`

Comment: ok but i don't get how to solve it. for example with sinh(3) i get an inf

Comment: @AmarildoAliaj Probably because `x!` overflows pretty quickly even the *double* type

Comment: Indeed, it will overflow the "normal" double type at 171. Did you change your factorial to return a double? If so, put a limit of 170 for `n`.

Comment: i don't change it... im not understanding can you please show me how it will be the code? Thanks